# ReleaseManagementBuild.exe to deploy Builds using CMD(Command Prompt)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, release-management, ms-release-management

I am trying to execute the ReleaseManagementBuild.exe using c# code(using cmd).

I got the following help :-

> ReleaseManagementBuild release {[-tfs teamFoundationServerUrl -tp
>   teamProjectName -bd buildDefinitionName -bn buildNumber] | [-rt
>   ReleaseTemplateName -pl PackageLocation [-an AppendComponentName] [-ff
>   FireAndForget]]} [-ts TargetStage]

Where:

-tfs     [TFS Mode] URL to the Team Foundation Server. The URL should include
           the collection if other than default.
  -tp      [TFS Mode] Name of the Team Project  for which the build was
           triggered.
  -bd      [TFS Mode] Name of the Build Definition used for the build.
  -bn      [TFS Mode] Build Number representing the specific build instance
           that generated the application components to release.

-rt      [Package Location Mode] Name of the release template used to create
           a new release.
  -pl      [Package Location Mode] Package location of the components
  -ts      [Optional] Name of the Target Stage where the release
           should stop.
  -ff      [Package Location Mode] [Optional] When set to True the command will
           return without waiting for the deployment in the first stage. Default
           is False: wait for the result.
  -an      [Package Location Mode] [Optional] In case where the Release
           Template has component that 'Builds Externally', when set to true,
           the component name will be appended at the end of the Package Location.

Examples:

ReleaseManagementBuild release -tfs http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection -tp "My Project" -bd "QA_Dev_MyApp_Manual" -bn "QA_Dev_MyApp_Manual_20101119.8"

ReleaseManagementBuild release -tfs http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection -tp "My Project" -bd "QA_Dev_MyApp_Manual" -bn "QA_Dev_MyApp_Manual_20101119.8" -ts "DEV"

ReleaseManagementBuild release -rt "My Release Template" -pl "//share/drop/version"

ReleaseManagementBuild release -rt "My Release Template" -pl "//share/drop/version" -ts "DEV" -ff False -an True

I want to pass these three parameters to the Build :-

1) Name of the release template used to create a new release.
2) Build Drop location 
3) Build number - I usually deploy the Build which is not the latest one.

So my question is how can I release by passing all the three parameters.

Note:- I was able to deploy by following :-

```
release -rt MY_ReleaseTemplate_RT -pl \\Server\BuildDrop\Dev1\BuildDefinitionName\BuildNumber
```

**But this is giving Build number in Release Management tool as Blank.** I want to do the release using package location as I can not set Build definition to auto deploy and also want the Build number to reflect in the Release Management tool.

Comment: Which version of TFS and release management are you using?

Comment: Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2015
and Release Management Server for TFS 2015

Comment: Since you are using TFS 2015, it's suggested using the release service. Release Management features have been integrated into the Build & Release hub in TFS 2015 Update 2 and above and VSTS. The newer web-based version is the recommended alternative to the server and client version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/overview?view=vsts

Answer (score 0):

The build drop location will be automatically determined if you specify a build number; you don't need to specify a drop location. You can specify any build number you'd like, it doesn't have to be the latest build.

Just follow the pattern set in the first example, `ReleaseManagementBuild release -tfs http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection -tp "My Project" -bd "QA_Dev_MyApp_Manual" -bn "QA_Dev_MyApp_Manual_20101119.8"`.

There's no other way to get the build number to show up in the release; either the release is tied to a specific build definition and number, or it's tied to a UNC location. It can't be both.

It's also worth noting that RM Server is **deprecated**. It's time to start planning a migration path to a modern version of TFS and the modern build/deployment capabilities that are present.

Comment: I did use the pattern told by you and did the release using UNC location. But if after the deployments someone wants to test if the correct build number was deployed or not. Then HOW can I verify the Build number deployed

Comment: Like I said, you can't do both. A release is either from a user-specified UNC location or from a specific build, but never both. If you specify a build, you have a build number. If you specify a UNC path, you don't and can't.

Comment: Ok, then If I use UNC to deploy code and someone tells that I have deployed the wrong Build number, then how can I tell him the Source UNC for my release. Is there way for logging or verifying the UNC location from where is the release done?

Comment: @VikasGoyal You may consider using Release service, instead of command line, to create a release definition. In this way, each release will have log to track the release process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/what-is-release-management?view=vsts